# Spring Data JPA with Liquibase correct configuration

Tags: spring-data-jpa, liquibase

Both Spring Data JPA and Liquibase have DB initialization and DDL modification capabilities.

So for the properties:-

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=<never/always/embedded>
```

or

```
spring.sql.init.mode=<never/always/embedded>
```

plus

```
spring.datasource.initialize=<true/false>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

along with :-

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

What is the correct mix and match?

Answer (score 0):

Both `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` are fine, while doing the prototyping. On this stage I would recommend just to pick one of this two possible options and go ahead with the logic you wanted to implement. But when it comes to productive code which brings the necessity of maintaining the schema version and schema diffs through the time, I wouldn't recommend both of them and recommend to use Liquibase as is. Here are the possible drawbacks:

- JPA `auto-ddl` releases you from the manual writing of SQL code, but it does implicit DB changes in the schema itself, which is pretty hard to track over time, cause you always need to align the schema and the code from entity definitions.
- Spring `schema.sql` initialization is pretty transparent but it doesn't allow you to track the history of the schema without extra effort (tracking git history of schema.sql for example :D ) and also no rollback option (and no db agnostic features aw)

So for prototyping any option works (better to pick one), but for production I recommend Liqiubase (or Flyway, that works as well).